# Error during saving query data into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I am trying to access sqlite db - test.db and running simple query `"SELECT * FROM TABLE"`  and trying to save it in dataframe. It seems the code is fine as I searched and found similar codes that seem to work for others. 
**NOTE:** I am running the code in Jupyter iNotebook.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
myFrames = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE", con)
```

I get error

> Error OperationalError: near "TABLE": syntax error
>
> *(lots of lines in between)*
>
> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM TABLE': near "TABLE": syntax error

Also, This piece prints out rows very well. So connection is working

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test_rank"):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Table is reserved word in SQL. You need to give the real name of the table or rename otherwise.

Comment: @Mokshyam Thanks that worked. I have making silly mistake

Comment: No worries. All of us do. Tick the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table** is a reserved keyword. Replace it with the real name of the table.